# call a modem using ubuntu and a iphone

Tags: command-line, usb-modem, iphone

I'm having a pc with ubuntu, and want to call a machine with a modem on it.
The things I have in my work is the following, my pc with ubuntu, my iphone.

Is it possible to call ( in this case a weather station with a modem, with a gsm sim-card ) this station with my pc, using my iphone to call a phone number ?

Now I'm using gtkterm and a serial cable, direct into the weather station, but I want to call the modem who's connected to the station ( so I could program from distance )

Do anybody know a good solution to this ?

Comment: I doubt the iPhone includes a modem function to made this possible.